# input a noun to get another noun that has the similar meaning. python, nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

> input: noun
>
> output: noun

example:

Input: dog, I want to get an output of cat, wolf, tiger

or

Input: computer, I want to get an output of laptop, tablet, phone, etc.

can anyone write a python code that does this? preferbably using NLTK?

sample code:

```
text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in nltk.corpus.treebank.words())
y= text.similar('dog')
print (y)
```

Update : found this and it works better

```
from py_thesaurus import Thesaurus
thesaurus = Thesaurus('dog')
print(thesaurus.get_synonym())
```

Comment: Can you please post a piece of code you have tried?

Comment: it's preferred that you edit your question and add the code there

Comment: @lee: what issue you are facing in above code? Can you please be more clear?

Comment: I will get "No matches" or "None".. just wondering is there a better way in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For dog, even I am getting "No Matches".

Similar words depends upon corpus you are using. For now I have used the same corpus you used.

**Code:**

```
import nltk

text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in nltk.corpus.treebank.words())
text.similar('computer')

similar_words = text._word_context_index.similar_words('computer')
print(similar_words)
```

**Output:**

```
industrial insurance research manufacturing market car farm trading
presence stored
['manufacturing', 'industrial', 'insurance', 'research', 'market', 'presence', 'farm', 'trading', 'stored', 'car']
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Welcome. You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers